# Dynamically-sized stack - follow-up 2

Tags: c, stack

Follow up of - [Dynamically-sized stack - follow up](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62589/dynamically-sized-stack-follow-up/62598#62598)

I've took the tips given to me, and what I did now is:

- changing the function names to have a prefix
- making the `pop()` function only popping and not returning the value as well
- checking for OOM exception / scenario that 0 is passed to `capacityIncrement` variable when initializing the stack (in those cases, if trying to push values to the stack, just ignore)
- added a decrement mechanism, when popping values a check will be made to see if there are (`capacityIncrement / 2 + capacityIncrement`) elements in the stack that are not in use, and if so, decrement the stack size by `capacityIncrement`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct
{
    int *elementData;
    unsigned int stackSize;
    unsigned int capacityIncrement;
    unsigned int elementCount;
} Stack;

void stack_initialize(Stack*, unsigned int);
void stack_push(Stack*, int);
void stack_pop(Stack*);
int stack_peek(const Stack*);
void stack_destroy(Stack*);
bool stack_isEmpty(const Stack*);
void stack_setCapacityIncrement(Stack*, unsigned int);
unsigned int stack_getCapacityIncrement(const Stack*);
unsigned int stack_getNumberOfElements(const Stack*);
unsigned int stack_getSize(const Stack*);

int main()
{
    Stack s1;
    stack_initialize(&s1, 4);
    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        stack_push(&s1, i + 1);
    }
    stack_pop(&s1);
    stack_push(&s1, 88);
    stack_push(&s1, 25);
    printf("The top of the stack is %d.\n", stack_peek(&s1));
    while(!stack_isEmpty(&s1))
    {
        int top = stack_peek(&s1);
        stack_pop(&s1);
        printf("Popping %d from the top of the stack.\n", top);
        printf("Size of stack is %d.\n", s1.stackSize);
    }
    return 0;
}

void stack_initialize(Stack *p, unsigned int capacityIncrement)
{
    p->elementData = NULL;
    p->stackSize = 0;
    p->capacityIncrement = capacityIncrement;
    p->elementCount = 0;
}

void stack_push(Stack *p, int value)
{
    if (p->elementCount == p->stackSize)
    {
        int newStackSize = p->stackSize + p->capacityIncrement;
        void *temp = realloc(p->elementData, sizeof(*p->elementData) * newStackSize);
        if (temp == NULL || newStackSize == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        p->stackSize = newStackSize;
        p->elementData = temp;
    }
    p->elementData[p->elementCount] = value;
    p->elementCount++;
}

void stack_pop(Stack *p)
{
    if (!stack_isEmpty(p))
    {
        p->elementCount--;
        if(p->stackSize - p->elementCount == p->capacityIncrement / 2 + p->capacityIncrement)
        {
            int newStackSize = p->stackSize - p->capacityIncrement;
            p->elementData = realloc(p->elementData, sizeof(*p->elementData) * newStackSize);
            p->stackSize = newStackSize;
        }
    }
}

int stack_peek(const Stack *p)
{
    if (!stack_isEmpty(p))
    {
        return p->elementData[p->elementCount - 1];
    }
    return 0;
}

void stack_destroy(Stack *p)
{
    free(p);
}

bool stack_isEmpty(const Stack *p)
{
    return p->elementCount == 0;
}

void stack_setCapacityIncrement(Stack *p, unsigned int capacityIncrement)
{
    p->capacityIncrement = capacityIncrement;
}

unsigned int stack_getCapacityIncrement(const Stack *p)
{
    return p->capacityIncrement;
}

unsigned int stack_getNumberOfElements(const Stack *p)
{
    return p->elementCount;
}

unsigned int stack_getSize(const Stack *p)
{
    return p->stackSize;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use same case prefix for type "Stack" and functions "stack" --> "gStack" or whatever.
2. Use correct print specifier.  This implies that either OP does not have all warnings enabled or is using a weak compiler.  Suggest remedying that.

   ```
   // printf("Size of stack is %d.\n", s1.stackSize);
   printf("Size of stack is %u.\n", s1.stackSize);
   ```
3. Use consistent sign-ness

   ```
   // int newStackSize;
   unsigned newStackSize;
   ```
4. In `push()`, `newStackSize` test should be corrected or eliminated.

   ```
   // if (temp == NULL || newStackSize == 0)

   if (temp == NULL && newStackSize > 0)

   // or if confident newStackSize will never be 0 here
   if (temp == NULL)
   ```
5. Silently failing `push()` due to OOM is a concern.
6. `pop()` should do similar OOM protection as `pop()`.  Even though it sounds silly that reducing memory usage should ever fail.
7. Consider putting all memory allocation into one helper function.  (BTW: `destroy()` did not free `p->elementData`.

   ```
   static int stack_realloc(int **ptr, unsigned *oldsize, unsigned newsize) {
     if (newsize > 0) {
       void *newptr = realloc(*ptr, newsize);
       if (newptr == NULL) return 1; // fail
       *ptr = newptr;
     }
     else {
       free(*ptr);
       *ptr = NULL;
     }
     *oldsize = newsize;
     return 0; // success;
   }

   // push()
   unsigned newStackSize = p->stackSize + p->capacityIncrement;
   if (stack_realloc(&p->elementData, &p->stackSize, newStackSize);

   // pop()
   // change from == to >=
   if(p->stackSize - p->elementCount >= p->capacityIncrement / 2 + p->capacityIncrement) {
     unsigned newStackSize = p->stackSize - p->capacityIncrement;
     // No problem is realloc failed, just continue with current stack
     stack_realloc(&p->elementData, &p->stackSize, newStackSize);

   // destroy() 
   stack_realloc(&p->elementData, &p->stackSize, 0);
   // Do not free `p`.
   // free(p);
   ```

Comment: @gues532 I'd use `size_t` over `unsigned`, but we've gone over that before.

Comment: I'm having couple of difficulties with your corrections : 4. I don't understand why it should be && and not ||. In a case that capacityIncrement is set to 0 and we try to push a value for the first time, let's say temp will point to an address which is NOT NULL, the newStackSize will equal 0 and because of the && we'll skip the if statement and try to push a value to a 0 bytes address.    6. I've thought about it, but how would such scenario where if we decrement the size it'll fail due to OOM exception, mind giving an example ?                7. Why didn't it free elementData exatcly ?

Comment: About size_T I haven't worked with it yet and I don't understand what is it exactly ? Is it a structure ? The only thing I've understood from reading online that it's the same as unsigned integer, yet it doesn't tell me what it is (structure I assume ? ) and why should I prefer it over unsigned int if it's basically an unsigned int ?

Comment: `size_t` is the type of unsigned integer returned from `sizeof()`.  Sometimes it is wider than `unsigned`.  So it always covers the index-able range for arrays.  It is also the type returned by `strlen()`, used in `memcpy()`, etc.

Comment: When `push()` occurs, the `newsize` must always be greater than the current size.   If code's `newsize` calculation ever resulted in a equal or less value the rest of code will not work as the stack will be too small.   This has nothing to do with a `realloc()` failure.  If `newsize <= p->elementCount`, code should test and cope with that _before_ calling `realloc()`. Thus `push()` should only ever call `realloc()` with a `newsize >= 1`.

Comment: When `realloc()` is called (via `push()`, `pop()` or whatever) it is passed a `newsize`.  On failure, `realloc()` returns `NULL`.  If `newsize` is 0, `realloc()` may also return `NULL`.  That is why the test for `realloc()` failure is `if (newptr == NULL && newsize > 0)`.

Comment: `realloc()` may fail when the size is reduced. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541215/should-i-enforce-realloc-check-if-the-new-block-size-is-smaller-than-the-initial/2541411

Comment: I understand why you say that the if statement should be if (newptr == NULL && newsize > 0) but what I did was making it | instead of && because in both cased if there was an OOM exception / if there wasn't but newSize was 0 I dealt with both scenarios similarly by just returning. I could also make it to return an integer instead of void so users will know an error happened due to OOM exception / size equal to 0 but in any way I dealt with both scenarios the same.

Comment: About the size_t, I'm not sure I've understood your explanation about it, "sometimes it is wider than unsigned" does it mean it's range is larger ? and why only sometimes ? Also, this didn't really tell me why it's preferred over unsigned int, I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Suggest inside `stack_initialize()`, add `if (capacityIncrement == 0) capacityIncrement++;`.

Comment: `size_t` is scaled to the memory size. `unsigned` is scaled to the native size of the CPU.  These are separate issues.  See SO questions like [Ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550774/what-is-size-t-in-c)

Comment: I don't understand why you change the if function in pop from == to >= we pop 1 element at a time so how could we skip this value ? Also about the stack_destroy you didn't explain me why it doesn't free the elementData pointed addresses ? And 1 more thing, I've already saw this question you linked me about size_t but it's really vague, ok I see that it's type of unsigned int/long and it's the type returned by many functions for some reason, but with all this I wasn't able to understand why I should use it instead of unsigned int.

Comment: 1) `from == to >=`  --> if downsizing the stack failed. 2) `stack_destroy()` never does `free(p->elementData}`.  In fact, it should _not_ call `free(p)` as `p` was not created via a `malloc()`.

Comment: `size_t`:  Ask yourself "Why not use `unsigned char`, `unsigned short`, `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` instead of `unsigned` for your stack index variable?"  What is the _right_ size?  `unsigned char` seems small and `unsigned long long` appears way to excessive.  Would not it be nice if the OS provided an unsigned type that was right size?  Something that could hold every index into an array that might ever occur and not be excessively long?  Hmm - that is `size_t`.

Comment: size_t : According to you the MAX_SIZE of size_t is dynamic, but from what I've read it's either 32 bit / 64 bit depending on the OS bit number. Mind elaborating ? (I know I ask alot about it but I'm having difficulties understanding it so bare with me :) )

Comment: from == to >= : I've read your answer you made in the question you gave me regarding if realloc to lower size can fail, and from what I've read technically it can't fail. Further more it was said that if the size is 0 it might return a pointer to NULL, but if our new stack size is 0 we'll never shrink the stack size from capacityIncrement back to 0 because the if(newStackSize > 0) will be skipped (just something I've noticed now)

Comment: The C spec does not specify that a size reduced call to `realloc()` cannot fail.  Therefore it can.  Suggest citing your references that say is cannot fail.  If you are confident that the `newsize` will 
_never_ be 0, then the concerns about calling `realloc()` with size 0 are moot.  IMO, the newsize calculation on a `pop()` should be separate from the `realloc()` call function or its wrapper funciton.  Therefore such a `realloc()` should be prepared for any newsize including 0.

Comment: `SIZE_MAX` is constant.  `size_t` is not only 32 or 64 bits.  C spec specifies it at _least_ 16 bits.  It could be 18, 36, etc.  It is dependent on the compiler's model of memory, not the OS.  Strongly recommend searching for a draft version of the C99 and/or C11 spec as the references you are referring to not jibe with my C spec understanding.

Comment: @Ok I've made some changes to the code, I'll open a question following this one, although I didn't changed unsigned int to size_t because my lack of understanding why it's preferred (problem on my side), but I'm fine with unsigned int for now because I'm currently just learning C and I'm sure I'll learn about size_t in the future and when I'll get to this point I'll probably reconsider changing it to size_t when I'll have better understanding of it.